# Why is Azure httpTrigger waiting for queueTrigger to finish processing?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-queues, azure-http-trigger

I have an http triggered function and a queue triggered function running on the same consumption plan in Python.

**Http Trigger:** The function receives an Id and sends it to the queue storage and returns the queue id. This takes a few milliseconds.

**Queue Trigger:** Gets triggered when the http trigger sends the message and does some processing. This takes around 5 minutes and uses around 40% of the CPU.

**The problem:**

If the http trigger receives a request while the queue trigger is still processing, the http trigger takes around 5 minutes to respond. Basically waiting for the queue processing to finish. I don't really to understand this behavior and looking for an explanation or a configuration setting to fix this.

[image: Sample Log]

As you can see the http trigger started execution at 03:04:33.367 but the first line of code in that function which is a log statement didn't print until 03:9:42.195 which is around 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, since Python is single threaded you will need to set the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT to 2 which is by default set to 1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference