# Azure Message Not Showing In Queue - Python SDK

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am working on a function app (python v2 model) that puts a message into an Azure Queue.

- When I run the function from the project, I get a successful response BUT the message does not actually show up in the queue.
- When I run the function outside of my VS Code environment (Jupyter notebook), the message shows in the queue.

Below is a sample of the function:

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueMessage
import logging
........
def add_message_to_queue(queue_name, connection_string, message):
    # Create a QueueServiceClient using the connection string
    queue_service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # Get the queue client
    queue_client = queue_service_client.get_queue_client(queue_name)

    # Add the message to the queue
    queue_client.send_message(message)
    return queue_client.send_message(message)

    
    
def addTolog_queue(message):

    queue_name = 'xxxxxxx'
    connection_string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

    return add_message_to_queue(queue_name, connection_string, message)


@app.route(route="xxxxx", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def xxxxxx(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:

    .............
    print(addTolog_queue(log_payload))
    
    return func.HttpResponse(
            body=json.dumps({}),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
        )


@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="xxxxxxx",
                               connection="xxxxxx_STORAGE") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    
    que_payload = azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    print(que_payload)
    print("posting")
    post_log(que_payload)
```

The response from the function is the following (displayed from the print statement.)

```
{'id': '1f5fe7dd-6d69-45d1-9bf4-86e62a3e4249', 'inserted_on': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15, 6, 43, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'expires_on': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 22, 6, 43, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'dequeue_count': None, 'content': xxxxxxxxxx, 'pop_receipt': 'AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAACVCVECIv2gE=', 'next_visible_on': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15, 6, 43, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
```

Has anyone ran into this before? Any ideas on how to fix it? I could not find single article  where someone ran into the same issue.

**UPDATE #1**

Strangely enough, I created a brand new queue and the message successful enters the queue on the Azure portal. I still don't know why but this is concerning functionality. Something is compromising the other queues from fully ingesting the message.

**UPDATE #2**

Getting closer...

I noticed when I remove the Queue function, the problem goes away. When I re-add the problem starts again. The issue has something to with the fact that I'm adding a message to a queue in the same environment that is triggered off adding the message to the queue.

Related article, although increasing workers has not helped: [Why is Azure httpTrigger waiting for queueTrigger to finish processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75528443/why-is-azure-httptrigger-waiting-for-queuetrigger-to-finish-processing)

Comment: Can you confirm that which functions trigger you are using?

Comment: The function is using a HTTP trigger AND a queue trigger. I'm begging to think it's just not supported.

Comment: Can you try to run both triggers in the v2 function model?

Comment: Yes I am running them in the V2 model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried the below code and was able to see the message sent to the storage queue with HTTP and queue trigger functions in the v2 model.*

**Code :**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueMessage
import logging
import json
import os

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

def add_message_to_queue(queue_name, connection_string, message):
    queue_service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    queue_client = queue_service_client.get_queue_client(queue_name)

    queue_client.send_message(message)
    return queue_client.send_message(message)

def addTolog_queue(message):
    queue_name = 'kamque'
    connection_string = os.environ['QueueStorageConnection']
    return add_message_to_queue(queue_name, connection_string, message)

@app.route(route="myfunction", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def my_function(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    log_payload = "Hi Kamali!" 
    print(addTolog_queue(log_payload))
    
    return func.HttpResponse(
            body=json.dumps({}),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
        )

def post_log(data):
    pass

@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="kamque", connection="QueueStorageConnection") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s', azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    
    que_payload = azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    print(que_payload)
    print("posting")
    post_log(que_payload)
```

**local.settings.json :**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "QueueStorageConnection": "<connec_string>"
  }
}
```

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I got below with the above HTTP trigger output URL,

[image]

I got the below response in the output terminal,

[image]
[image]

As mentioned in the above output **message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'kamque-poison'**. I got the message in the kamque-poison as below,

[image]

Then, I send a message to the queue as below,

[image]

***I got the message from the storage queue for the queue trigger function as below,***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details. This was super helpful.

I think I figured out the issue on my side. Very silly - the queue trigger automatically removes the record from the queue, so I kept checking the queue after it had already been removed. 

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Very silly - the queue trigger automatically removes the record from the queue, so I kept checking the queue after it had already been removed.